# Need a bulk insert tip

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, bulkinsert

I need to insert a table data into another table. Where it is not guaranteed that the source table have all rows correctly where some of the not null fields are having null values. So with this source table I need to enter all valid rows into the table and find all unvalid rows which failed to insert and return them.

I know we can do this by validating all rows before hand. But as this is a bulk insert from a csv and parsed by .net code so from db we wil not validate it but directly enter.

We can also do this by running a loop but performance might hit.

so my question is is any way where we can use a single statement for insert and skip rows which has a problem and insert which are valid.

Comment: Can you not validate the data in your .NET code before inserting it?

Comment: Yes they are already validating it. But still want to return error rows if any after inserting them by bulk.

Answer (score 0):

BULK INSERT is all-or-nothing. SQL Server does not have the ability to shunt erroneous rows into a separate table, alas.

The best thing you can do is to validate all data thoroughly before inserting it. If the insert still fails (maybe due to a bug) you need to retry all rows one-by-one and log the errors that are occurring.

You can also bulk insert to a temp table and move the rows from there to the final table one-by-one.